# How to select elements from json using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

## How can I select specific elements, arrays or objects from JSON?

I can't figure out how to select a specific element in a JSON object and I can't come up with a search phrase to google.

## Example selecting this

```
{
   'entities':[
      {
         'start':25,
         'end':26,
         'value':'1',
         'entity':'Dosage',
         'confidence':0.9871567711054905,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      },
      {
         'start':27,
         'end':34,
         'value':'capsule',
         'entity':'Form',
         'confidence':0.9894495817539142,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      },
      {
         'start':38,
         'end':43,
         'value':'Advil',
         'entity':'Drug',
         'confidence':0.9801160225829469,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      },
      {
         'start':49,
         'end':56,
         'value':'6 jours',
         'entity':'Duration',
         'confidence':0.9675590550065555,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      }
   ],
   'text':'le patient a été prescrit 1 capsule de Advil pour 6 jours'
}
```

## From this JSON

```
data = {
   'intent':{
      'name':'greet',
      'confidence':0.7038594484329224
   },
   'entities':[
      {
         'start':25,
         'end':26,
         'value':'1',
         'entity':'Dosage',
         'confidence':0.9871567711054905,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      },
      {
         'start':27,
         'end':34,
         'value':'capsule',
         'entity':'Form',
         'confidence':0.9894495817539142,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      },
      {
         'start':38,
         'end':43,
         'value':'Advil',
         'entity':'Drug',
         'confidence':0.9801160225829469,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      },
      {
         'start':49,
         'end':56,
         'value':'6 jours',
         'entity':'Duration',
         'confidence':0.9675590550065555,
         'extractor':'CRFEntityExtractor'
      }
   ],
   'intent_ranking':[
      {
         'name':'greet',
         'confidence':0.7038594484329224
      },
      {
         'name':'bye',
         'confidence':0.6136901378631592
      }
   ],
   'text':'le patient a été prescrit 1 capsule de Advil pour 6 jours'
}
```

I've already tried this method by deleting 'intent' and 'intent_ranking' but I'm afraid that if the JSON is empty the code will crash

```
    if "intent" in data:
        del data["intent"], data["intent_ranking"]
    return data
```

I'm trying to select just 'entities' and append it into

```
result = {}
```

Comment: I'd say the simplest solution would be: `{'entities': data['entities']}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't just selecting what you whant work?

```
data = data['entities']
```

and if you needed exactly as you stated you can build it,

```
new_data = {
 'entities' : data['entities'],
 'text' : data['text']
}
data = new_data
```

you keep the name if needed

Hope it helped, not sur I have understood your question but if it did help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the part you need, you can just create a new dictionary called result, and add the entities and text content of the data variable. The code will not crash if the `data['entities']` and `data['text']` always exit:

```
result = data['entities']
result.append(data['text'])
print (result)
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include descriptive prose to explain why this addressed the original asker's question?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, doing

```
if "key" in data:
    del data["key"]
```

will not crash if `data` is empty.

However, the answers above are more suitable imo.